# Octave vectorize loop: for i = 1:size(v,1) v(i,y(i)) = 1; end

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave, vectorization

Assume:

```
v = zeros(4,3)
```

and

```
y = [1;2;1;3]
```

Any way to do the following:

```
for i = 1:size(v,1) 
    v(i,y(i)) = 1;
end
```

in a vectorized fashion?

For example, the following does not work:

```
v(:,y) = 1
```

TIA

Comment: Dan, thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this fits your purposes:

```
v(full(sparse(1:size(v, 1), y, true))) = 1
```

Comment: Just one question. Why not just use: `full(sparse(1:size(v, 1), y, 1 ))`? Why the last assignment to 1?

Comment: @user2051561 No specific reason actually. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate, I've seen it asked a few times for Matlab. But I can't find them now. Here is one way using [linear indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/08/linear-indexing/), which you can find using the `sub2ind` function:

```
v(sub2ind(size(v), (1:length(y))', y)) = 1
```

Breaking it down

```
colIndex = y;
rowIndex = 1:length(y);
linearIndex = sub2ind(size(v), rowIndex', colIndex);
v(linearIndex) = 1;
```

Comment: This also works. Gave Yuri the green because he answered first. Also appreciate the explanation you give. Thanks.

Comment: @user2051561 haha no problem, although technically I was first by 19 seconds ;)

Comment: Oops. 8-( Sorry about that. Were can we check who answered first? I assumed the order of input showed this.

Comment: @user2051561 don't worry about it. If you hover over the answered time (i.e. the 4 hours ago bit) then it tells you in the tooltip. The order is based on votes which makes more sense as you'd want the most correct answer at the top rather than the first answer